# Would it be possible to use different note symbols with pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

When annotating a pdf in pdfview with the pdf-tools capabilities, I noticed that the symbols I can use are the same symbols evince uses. Can I use different custom symbols on i.e. text notes and if so how?

Steps I have undertaken to answer the question myself:

1. I found the function evoked to place annotations
   `(pdf-annot-add-text-annotation POS &optional ICON PROPERTY-ALIST)`
2. I found that in that function the function `pdf-annot-add-annotation` is evoked. I assume this is the function that places the symbol
3. I found that there is a list of strings `pdf-annot-standard-text-icons` which lists the names of the symbols like `Note` and `Comment`.

What I wasn't able to find was where the actual symbols are taken from. If replacing is not quite so easy, is there a way to scale the symbols placed smaller?

Answer (score 1):

The docstring of `pdf-annot-text-annotation-size` (a constant) reads:

```
  The Size of text and file annotations in PDF points.

These values are hard-coded in poppler.  And while the size of
these annotations may be changed, i.e. the edges property, it has
no effect on the rendering.)
```

Therefore, the icon rendering size can not be changed.

If this has very high priority for you, then you could consider to (additionally) use the [vimura-server](https://pypi.org/project/vimura-server/) i.c.w. the [add-pymupdf-backend branch](https://github.com/dalanicolai/pdf-tools/tree/add-pymupdf-backend) of my fork of pdf-tools (it also adds a line annotation feature).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I wlll look into this!